# Как реализовать переход с одного popup окна на другое popup окно?

Tags: html, jquery, css

[Проект](http://martynuk.esy.es/)

Есть popup окно на jquery, и кнопкой далее, (жмем пункт меню **Как играть**),

//код без стилей

```js
 $('a.close').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().fadeOut(100);
   $('#overlay').remove('#overlay');
   return false;
 });

 $('a.show_popup__rules').click(function() {
   $('div.' + $(this).attr("rel")).fadeIn(500);
   $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
   $('#overlay').show().css({
     'filter': 'alpha(opacity=70)'
   });
   return false;
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step-one" class="popup__rules step1">
  <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
  <div class="popup__head">Как играть?</div>
  <div class="popup__content">
    <p>Выберите интересующий Вас предмет или игру:</p>
    <div class="pic__wrap">
      <img src="../img/mini-pic-step1.png" alt="mini">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup__footer">
    <a href="#step-two" class="popup_next">Далее</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="step-two" class="popup__rules step2">
  <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
  <div class="popup__head">Как играть?</div>
  <div class="popup__content">
    <p>Выберите свободную ячейку или нажмите кнопку "Занять случайное место". Чем больше мест вы займете, тем выше шанс победить!</p>
    <div class="pic__wrap">
      <img src="../img/mini-pic-step2.png" alt="mini">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup__footer">
    <a href="#step-one" class="popup_prev">Назад</a>
    <a href="#step-three" class="popup_next">Далее</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

а также второе popup окно, пытаюсь битый час реализовать переход между ними при нажатии на кнопку. Как это по простому реализовать? Подскажите.

Answer (score 2):

Проблему решилась вот таким образом:

```html
<div id="step-one" class="popup__rules step1">
  <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
  <div class="popup__head">Как играть?</div>
  <div class="popup__content">
    <p>Выберите интересующий Вас предмет или игру:</p>
    <div class="pic__wrap">
      <img src="../img/mini-pic-step1.png" alt="mini">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup__footer">
    <a href="#step-two" class="popup_next" onclick="nextStep(1)">Далее</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="step-two" class="popup__rules step2">
  <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
  <div class="popup__head">Как играть?</div>
  <div class="popup__content">
    <p>Выберите свободную ячейку или нажмите кнопку "Занять случайное место". Чем больше мест вы займете, тем выше шанс победить!</p>
    <div class="pic__wrap">
      <img src="../img/mini-pic-step2.png" alt="mini">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup__footer">
    <a href="#step-one" class="popup_prev" onclick="prevStep(1)">Назад</a>
    <a href="#step-three" class="popup_next" onclick="nextStep(2)">Далее</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="step-three" class="popup__rules step3">
  <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
  <div class="popup__head">Как играть?</div>
  <div class="popup__content">
    <p>Когда все места будут заняты, система автоматически выберет победителя на сайте <a href="#" class="random">random.org</a> и он получит предмет или игру.</p>

    <p>Желаем удачи!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="popup__footer">
    <a href="#step-one" class="popup_prev" onclick="prevStep(2)">Назад</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function nextStep($step) {
    if ($step == 1) {
      $("#step-one").hide();
      $("#step-two").show();

    } else if ($step == 2) {
      $("#step-two").hide();
      $("#step-three").show();
    }
  }

  function prevStep($step) {
    if ($step == 1) {
      $("#step-one").show();
      $("#step-two").hide();

    } else if ($step == 2) {
      $("#step-two").show();
      $("#step-three").hide();
    }
  }
</script>
```